# Redis error: ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database

Tags: flask, redis, celery

with

```
flask-caching==1.7.2
flask==1.0.3
redis==3.2.1
celery==4.3.0
```

I heve net blinking error

```
Cannot route message for exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox': Table empty or key no longer exists. 
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.reply.celery.pidbox') has been removed from the Redis database.
```

I configure flask cache with

```
# redis
REDIS_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']       
# flask-caching
CACHE_TYPE = 'redis'
CACHE_KEY_PREFIX = 'glue_flask_cache_'
CACHE_REDIS_URL = REDIS_URL
```

Any ideas what to with this errors and how to fix them ?

Answer (score 4):

Known issue - https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1063 - should have been fixed in one of the 4.6.x released but it seems like it is not...